# Flexcube - Customer Account's status change from/to 'OVER' / 'NORM'

Tags: oracle

On Oracle Flexcube, in the **sttm_cust_account** table, there is an **'ACC_STATUS'** column.
In this column value changes from/to **'OVER' <> 'NORM'** on some conditions.
I need to find when and where this status changes? This status changes during EOD or changes with any JOB? Do anyone knows in which packages I can found logic?
I know the module where we can change manually status.
But now I need to find place where automatically changes these statuses

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Flexcube 14.0 and above is applicable that the automatic status change logic you must check the [STATUS RULE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E94300_01/html/CASA/CASA03_A_AccountClass.htm#Raf_toc327545502) button in Account class maintenance screen(Function_id:-**STDACCLS**).
The Automatic status change happens during EOD.

Also at the Account class level there is a Preference as **Status change Automatic** which you can override at the Account level
to indicate whether status change is automatic for this account class or account.

For Manual status change you have to refer the screen (function id:-**STDSTCHN**).

Please find the below from the manual regarding STATUS RULE maintenance

In this screen, you can define five conditions for each status applicable to an account class. An account will be said to be in a specific status if any one of the five conditions associated with the status holds true for an account. Conversely, if all the conditions are false, the account will automatically move to the next available status for which the condition is true.

A user defined status INTR is used for both OD and Loan accounts. When a loan is in adversity status and the customer pays the entire overdue amount, the status of the loan changes to a user defined account status ‘INTR’ rather than ‘NORM’, so would the other OD and loan accounts of the same customer across branches.

Only backward movement of any other status to INTR is applicable. The account status cannot change from NORM to INTR. The status sequence of INTR is maintained as the immediate sequence number next to NORM.

The following elements are available based on which you can build a condition for automatic status change. You can associate each of these elements with an account, in the ‘Customer Accounts Maintenance’ screen.

The set of elements are as follows:

Frozen

Dormant

No Debits

No Credits

Stop Payment

Current Status

In addition, the following elements will also be available for processing:

OD (overdraft) Days

Inactive Days

Overline Days

TOD (Temporary Overdraft) Days

Customer Classification

Due Count

Overdue Days

Customer Credit Ranking

Debit Interest Overdue Days

Overdue Limit Breach Days

Overdue Expiry Days

Overdue No Credit days

Principal Overdue Days

Principal Overdue Amount

Principal Overdue Local Currency Equivalent Amount

Interest Overdue Days

Interest Overdue Amount

Interest Overdue Local Currency Equivalent Amount

Charge Overdue Days

Charge Overdue Amount

Charge Overdue Local Currency Equivalent Amount

Account Interim Days

Appropriation Preference

You can define the appropriation sequence for overdraft accounts for each account status.

Appropriation sequence maintenance is mandatory if the ‘Component-wise Tracking for Overdraft’ is checked.

The appropriation preference sequence can be modified anytime and this will be applicable for the existing accounts also.This modification will effect only for future credits and appropriation.

Component with priority 1

Select the component with first priority from the adjoining drop-down list. The options available are:

Principal

Interest

Charge

Component with priority 2

Select the component with second priority from the adjoining drop-down list. The options available are:

Principal

Interest

Charge

Component with priority 3

Select the component with third priority from the adjoining drop-down list. The options available are:

Principal

Interest

Charge

Status Change for Overdraft Accounts

Oracle FLEXCUBE processes the status change for overdraft accounts based on the following rules:

Debit Interest OD Days

OD Limit Breach Days

OD Expiry Days

No Credit days

Account Interim Days

Debit Interest OD Days

The system processes the status change on overdraft account, if the customer fails to pay the debit interest of the overdraft account for specified number of days.

For example,

OD Utilization date: 01-Jan-2011

Days after which Status Change should happen: 90 Days

Debit interest due date: 01-Feb-2011

In this example, the system modifies the customer account status based on the status rule maintenance, if the customer fails to pay the debit interest by 02-May-2011.

OD Limit Breach Days

The system processes the status change on OD account, if the OD limit of the overdraft account is breached for a specified number of days. The system tracks the overdraft limit breach days based on the utilizations done at the line level.

OD Expiry Days

The system processes the status change on overdraft account, if the OD utilization of the overdraft account is not settled beyond the expiry date.

No Credit Days

The system processes the status change on OD account if there is no credit transaction into the overdraft account for a specified number of days.

Logical Operators

Logical Operators are indicators of certain conditions that you specify while building a rule. These operators are used in combination with the elements discussed earlier. The following is a list of logical operators that you would require to build a status rule:

Operator

Description

AND

The conjunction ‘and’

OR

The conjunction ‘or’

> 

Greater than

> =

Greater than or equal to (please note that there is no space between the two symbols)

<

Less than

<=

Less than or equal to (please note that there is no space between the two symbols)

< >

Not equal to (please note that there is no space between the two symbols)

=

Equal to

Oracle FLEXCUBE allows data store for tracking of SOD debit interest due. During Interest liquidation for debit interest, the system populates the SOD Debit Interest Due Data Store with the Amount Due as debit interest for the SOD utilized amount and the due date of payment for the interest amount.

The debit interest due amount is adjusted in the SOD utilized amount and the system checks for any credit entries for the SOD corresponding to the debit interest. During EOD, if any credit entry exists for the account, then the system does adjustments on the amount due for the SOD debit interest due data store. The system also adjusts the debit interest payment against the oldest available debit interest due amount, and so on.

Oracle FLEXCUBE provides SDEs for ‘SOD Due Count’ and ‘SOD Overdue Days’ for status rule generation. During EOD while running the status update batch, the system calculates SDE ‘SOD Due Count’ value as the count of the records having due amount not equal to zero from the SOD debit interest due data store. The system updates the ‘SOD Overdue Days’ with the number of days since the last debit interest payment done for the account.

Oracle FLEXCUBE provides an account status called ‘DIDF’ for an SOD account, which is available as part of ‘Status Rule Screen’. If the ‘SOD Due Count ’or ‘SOD Overdue Days’ satisfies the condition specified in the status change rule, then the system changes the status for the account to ‘DIDF’.

While running the status change batch, the system updates the ‘No Debit’ flag as ‘Y’ for ‘DIDF’ status account. If payment for the debit interest happens on the SOD account against the utilized amount, and if on recalculation the value of SDE ‘SOD Due Count’, or ‘SOD Overdue Days’ is not met, the status batch changes the status of the OD account from ‘DIDF’ to the previous account status and updates the ‘No Debit’ flag as ‘N’.

For more information you can check the [CASA user manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E94300_01/html/CASA/CASATOC00.htm)

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed explanation.
Can you please also explain, how can I find EOD packages where automatic status change happens for customer accounts? I need to find out that on which package/s automatic status change happens during EOD

Comment: you can check this package CSPKS_CSDSTBTC_BATCH

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check the package

Comment: On the package 'CSPKS_CSDSTBTC_BATCH', I found the code which returns new status. Code like below

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN STPR#_' || L_TB_ACCOUNTS(I)
                           .ACCOUNT_CLASS || '(:1,:2,:3); END;'
            USING GLOBAL.CURRENT_BRANCH, L_TB_ACCOUNTS(I).CUST_AC_NO, OUT L_NEW_STATUS;

But I can not find any procedure like 'STPR#_'

How can I find this procedure? Is it creates also durind EOD dynamically?

Comment: STPR#_' || L_TB_ACCOUNTS(I) .ACCOUNT_CLASS  should be created when you unlock and save the account class.For example if your account class is 1006 then the procedure will be STPR#_1006

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolves your issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251101/discussion-between-alimusa-and-psaraj12).